# SlideJS not working, attempting to recreate website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to recreate a website that uses SlideJS with a caption that fades in with each button click. I have the exact same files however I am having an issue with making the images and the captions show up and stay.

Here is what the website looks like fully functioning.

i.gyazo.com/2db38f72dff333d3eab898b5981151d1.gif

Link to fully functioning design: http://web-beta.archive.org/web/20161006125524/http://murray-engineering.com

And now here is my issue:

i.gyazo.com/32905aca742dd967d1b00d5ff01eb1ce.gif

The images I attempted to add in appear and then leave the screen right away. Also, the captions do not show up at all.

Here's my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/banner-styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/iconochive.css">


<meta name="viewport" content="width=920">
<title>Akhetian Engineering</title>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://murray-engineering.com/wp-content/themes/murray_engineering/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/web-beta.archive.org\/web\/20161006125524\/https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/72x72\/","ext":".png","source":{"concatemoji":"https:\/\/web-beta.archive.org\/web\/20161006125524\/http:\/\/murray-engineering.com\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.5.3"}};
            !function(a,b,c){function d(a){var c,d,e,f=b.createElement("canvas"),g=f.getContext&&f.getContext("2d"),h=String.fromCharCode;if(!g||!g.fillText)return!1;switch(g.textBaseline="top",g.font="600 32px Arial",a){case"flag":return g.fillText(h(55356,56806,55356,56826),0,0),f.toDataURL().length>3e3;case"diversity":return g.fillText(h(55356,57221),0,0),c=g.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data,d=c[0]+","+c[1]+","+c[2]+","+c[3],g.fillText(h(55356,57221,55356,57343),0,0),c=g.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data,e=c[0]+","+c[1]+","+c[2]+","+c[3],d!==e;case"simple":return g.fillText(h(55357,56835),0,0),0!==g.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data[0];case"unicode8":return g.fillText(h(55356,57135),0,0),0!==g.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data[0]}return!1}function e(a){var c=b.createElement("script");c.src=a,c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}var f,g,h,i;for(i=Array("simple","flag","unicode8","diversity"),c.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},h=0;h<i.length;h++)c.supports[i[h]]=d(i[h]),c.supports.everything=c.supports.everything&&c.supports[i[h]],"flag"!==i[h]&&(c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&c.supports[i[h]]);c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!c.supports.flag,c.DOMReady=!1,c.readyCallback=function(){c.DOMReady=!0},c.supports.everything||(g=function(){c.readyCallback()},b.addEventListener?(b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",g,!1),a.addEventListener("load",g,!1)):(a.attachEvent("onload",g),b.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===b.readyState&&c.readyCallback()})),f=c.source||{},f.concatemoji?e(f.concatemoji):f.wpemoji&&f.twemoji&&(e(f.twemoji),e(f.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
        </script><script src="js/wp-emoji-release.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 .07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="main" class="site-main">
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
            <div class="site-branding">
                <a href="index.html" title="Murray Engineering" rel="home" class="site-logo"></a>
            </div>

            <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation-main" role="navigation">
                <h1 class="menu-toggle">Menu</h1>
                <div class="screen-reader-text skip-link"><a href="https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20161006125524/murray-engineering.com#content" title="Skip to content">Skip to content</a></div>

                <div class="menu-main-nav-container"><ul id="menu-main-nav" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-64" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-64"><a>projects</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-127" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-127"><a href="projects/educational-facilities/">Education</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-133" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-133"><a href="projects/projects-healthcare/">Health Care</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-131" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-131"><a href="projects/projects-historic-preservation/">Historic Preservation</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-129" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-129"><a href="projects/cultural-religious-buildings/">Institutional + Cultural</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-132" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-132"><a href="projects/projects-residential-2/">Multi-Family Residential</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-464" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-464"><a href="projects/multi-family-residential/">Residential</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-323" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-323"><a href="projects/retail/">Retail</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-130" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-130"><a href="projects/special-structures/">Special Structures</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17"><a href="services">services</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-713" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-713"><a href="people">about</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14"><a href="contact">contact</a></li>
</ul></div>         </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
        </header><!-- #masthead -->

<div class="site-body">
<div id="gallery" class="galleryWrap">
    <div class="slides_container">


    <div class="slides_control"><div class="nest">
            <img width="927" height="500" src="https://placehold.it/927x500" class="attachment-fullsize size-fullsize" alt="home_" srcset="https://placehold.it/927x500" sizes="(max-width: 927px) 100vw, 927px">

      <div class="galleryDescription">
              </div>
    </div><div class="nest">
            <img width="920" height="495" src="https://placehold.it/927x500" class="attachment-fullsize size-fullsize" alt="The Pederson house, Pederson, Kohn Fox, architect" srcset="https://placehold.it/927x500" sizes="(max-width: 920px) 100vw, 920px">
                <div class="captionWrapper bottom">
            <div class="captionText">Residential</div>
        </div>

      <div class="galleryDescription ">
        The Pederson house, Pederson, Kohn Fox, architect     </div>
    </div><div class="nest">
            <img width="920" height="495" src="images/institutional-cultural.jpg" class="attachment-fullsize size-fullsize" alt="The Granary, Gallery, Steven Lerner, architect" srcset="https://placehold.it/927x500" sizes="(max-width: 920px) 100vw, 920px">
                <div class="captionWrapper bottom-left ">
            <div class="captionText">Institutional + Cultural</div>
        </div>

      <div class="galleryDescription ">
        The Granary, Gallery, Steven Lerner, architect    </div>
    </div><div class="nest">
            <img width="920" height="495" src="images/residential-buildings.jpg" class="attachment-fullsize size-fullsize" alt="957 Pacific Street, Brooklyn, NY, Loading Dock 5 Architects" srcset="http://murray-engineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/residential-buildings.jpg 920w, http://murray-engineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/residential-buildings-300x161.jpg 300w" sizes="(max-width: 920px) 100vw, 920px">
                <div class="captionWrapper right-residential ">
            <div class="captionText">Multi Family Residential</div>
        </div>

      <div class="galleryDescription">
        957 Pacific Street, Brooklyn, NY, Loading Dock 5 Architects   </div>
    </div><div class="nest">
            <img width="920" height="495" src="images/health-care.jpg" class="attachment-fullsize size-fullsize" alt="Bellevue Cooling Center, Goldman Copeland Mechanical Consulting Engineers" srcset="http://murray-engineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/health-care.jpg 920w, http://murray-engineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/health-care-300x161.jpg 300w" sizes="(max-width: 920px) 100vw, 920px">
                <div class="captionWrapper right-health ">
            <div class="captionText">Health Care</div>
        </div>

      <div class="galleryDescription">
        Bellevue Cooling Center, Goldman Copeland Mechanical Consulting Engineers     </div>
    </div><div class="nest">
            <img width="920" height="495" src="images/historic-preservation.jpg" class="attachment-fullsize size-fullsize" alt="Cathedral of Saint Patrick, New York City" srcset="http://murray-engineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/historic-preservation.jpg 920w, http://murray-engineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/historic-preservation-300x161.jpg 300w" sizes="(max-width: 920px) 100vw, 920px">
                <div class="captionWrapper left ">
            <div class="captionText">Historic Preservation</div>
        </div>

      <div class="galleryDescription">
        Cathedral of Saint Patrick, New York City     </div>
    </div><div class="nest">
            <img width="920" height="495" src="images/special-structures.jpg" class="attachment-fullsize size-fullsize" alt="Rockaway Park Comfort Station, WXY Studio" srcset="http://murray-engineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/special-structures.jpg 920w, http://murray-engineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/special-structures-300x161.jpg 300w" sizes="(max-width: 920px) 100vw, 920px">
                <div class="captionWrapper bottom">
            <div class="captionText">Special Structures</div>
        </div>

      <div class="galleryDescription">
        Rockaway Park Comfort Station, WXY Studio     </div>
    </div><div class="nest">
            <img width="920" height="495" src="images/retail_homeslider.png" class="attachment-fullsize size-fullsize" alt="Armani Corporate Offices + Store, NYC" srcset="http://murray-engineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/retail_homeslider.png 920w, http://murray-engineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/retail_homeslider-300x161.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 920px) 100vw, 920px">
                <div class="captionWrapper right-residential ">
            <div class="captionText">Retail</div>
        </div>

      <div class="galleryDescription">
        Armani Corporate Offices + Store, NYC</div>
    </div></div>




        </div><!-- slides_container -->
      </div> <!-- site body -->
    </div><!-- site main-->
</div><!-- site -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/navigation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/skip-link-focus-fix.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/comment-reply.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wp-embed.min.js"></script>


<script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>

<script>
        $(function(){
            $('#gallery').slides({
                preload: false,
                play: 4000,
                effect: 'fade',
                crossfade: true,
                slideSpeed: 350,
                fadeSpeed: 500,
                currentClass: 'current', // string, Class name for current class
                generatePagination: true,
                animationStart: function(current){
                    $('.galleryDescription').removeClass("show");
                    $('.captionWrapper').removeClass("show");
                },
                animationComplete: function(current){
                    $('.galleryDescription').addClass("show");
                    $('.captionWrapper').addClass("show");

                },
                slidesLoaded: function() {
                    $('.galleryDescription').addClass("show");
                    $('.captionWrapper').addClass("show");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>


</body></html>
```

Comment: I really do need some help with this issue. If someone could please point me in the right direction I would very much appreciate that.